# How to handle SlideShowBegin Event in C#

Tags: c#

I found this: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff746741(v=office.15).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff746741%28v=office.15%29.aspx) ... but it is in VBA and I don´t know how can I transform it to C#. I need to start function SlideShow when slideshow begins. How can do this?

```
    private void SlideShow(xxx)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("SlideShow is running!");
    }
```

Comment: Are you writing a powerpoint addin?

Comment: Yes, I am writing a powerpoint addin. @soandos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    Application.SlideShowBegin += Application_SlideShowBegin;   
}



private void Application_SlideShowBegin(PowerPoint.SlideShowWindow Wn)
{
    // your implementation
}
```

Where ThisAddIn will be the name of your add in project name... I hope this is your answer.

Comment: no, I need event, because user can start slideshow from menu

Comment: Check my edit. It will fire when the f5 key is pressed down. Is it something else that you need?

Comment: I don´t want to start function when F5 is pressed down. I want to start function when slideshow begins. Slideshow could begins in more ways.

Comment: Check my edit. I think this is what you need. do tell me if this works

Comment: this is for what: Application.SlideShowBegin += Application_SlideShowBegin; I have errors on this line

Comment: Where are you writing this? This is adding the delegate so that when the slide show begins Application_SildeShowBegin is fired

Comment: @user3357400 Check my answer I edited it again, now you will understand. I tried this on my PC it is working.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54222/discussion-between-user3357400-and-syed-farjad-zia-zaidi).